# How to round values in a list containing tuples

Tags: python

I have a list, which has 2 more lists within it and both of the lists each have 2 tuples in them.

```py
lst = [
  [('Jade', 0.9877607), ('Tom', 0.5728347)],
  [('Jackson', 0.6892309), ('Hazel', 0.6837777)]
]
```

I want to round all 4 float values to 2 d.p. Would I have to turn each tuple into a list and then change it or is there an easier way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Tuples are unchangeable. So the only way is to convert the tuple into a list, change the list, and convert the list back into a tuple.

Comment: @nfn Tuples are immutable, but there is no need to convert them into a list. You can access the elements of a tuple directly in order to create new tuple.

Comment: approximating with `float`, `round`, `format` to n (dp) may lead a wrong approximation, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#round)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) are [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-immutable), you cannot modify them in-place. You'll need to create a new list based on the current list.

This is very simple to do using a list comprehension:

```
lst = [
    [('Jade', 0.9877607), ('Tom', 0.5728347)], 
    [('Jackson', 0.6892309), ('Hazel', 0.6837777)],
]

new_list = [
    [(name, round(value, 2)) for (name, value) in sublist]  
    for sublist in lst
]
print(new_list)

# Output:

# [
#    [('Jade', 0.99), ('Tom', 0.57)],
#    [('Jackson', 0.69), ('Hazel', 0.68)]
# ]
```

Comment: I have another problem following this up. What is the list in lst is None? Is there a way to get around this or no?

Comment: What do you want to do if it is `None`? And are you talking about the elements of `lst` being `None`, `[None, None]`, `[('some name', None), ('other name', None)]`? It's probably easier to ask a new question, there's not much space in the comments for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are immutable, which means if you want to "modify" them, you need to create whole new object. In your case it is easiest to create whole new list and reassign it to the original `lst` variable.

```
lst = [[(t[0], round(t[1], 2)) for t in lin] for lin in lst]
```

You could use the above [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to create a new list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in lst:
  print(round(x[0][1],2),round(x[1][1],2))

#output
0.99 0.57
0.69 0.68
```

Or if you want to create a new list:

```
k=[]
for x in lst:
  for y in x:
    k.append((y[0],round(y[1],2)))
```